# Joomla hosting problem

Tags: mysql, joomla, hosting

I have a Joomla website that works perfectly on localhost.

But I have problem when I try to upload it to online location.

I chose byethost because my boss told that's the hosting to use.

Now, I upload entire joomla website folder using FTP protocol application (FileZilla).
And then I have to create a database under specific name that always has pre-defined prefix. I believe that's what bothers me. The name of my database that I export using phpMyAdmin is melodija, but when I create new mySql database online (on a byethost server) I get some weird name like b23_4343_melodija and when I import my existing database in it, the FAIL happens. 
"Database Error: Unable to connect to the database:Could not connect to MySQL"

What should I do?

Comment: You can't get around the default prefix certain hosts prepend onto database names, you need to change the config to match. All db connections settings can be defined in configuration.php. PS - you should select the answer below that solved your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is becouse your configuration problems in the `configuration.php` file in the root web directory

in the configuration file check this part

```
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $user = 'root';
    var $db = 'wccms_db';
    var $dbprefix = 'jos_';
```

make sure that you have entered the valid information as your hosting provider provided you

as u indecated the database name  `b23_4343_melodija` (this may be as your hosting account userdetails name is generated coz the Mysql server is a shared server )

Comment: You select this answer as the solution, as it solved your problem.

Comment: I did, just now, forgot to do it yesterday :/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just rename the database? Joomla is configured for your old setup, so it's looking for the old database name. I Googled your problem, and I would check this out: http://tutorials.ausweb.com.au/web/Tutorials/Joomla-FAQ/Move-Joomla-Site-to-a-New-Server/

It looks like a comprehensive guide to moving a Joomla installation from one host to another.

Good luck *(and WordPress > Joomla :P)*!

Answer (score 0):

Either you could rename your database (e.g. using PhpMyAdmin) or you could change the database link in the joomla-file configuration.php (var $db = 'b23_4343_melodija';).

Comment: I will give it a go and post what happens.